# Use functions that return "Handler Text" in yesod-tests

Tags: haskell, yesod

Here's a (simplified) test I have

```
it "asserts route access for valid arguments" $ do
    -- ... 
    token <- getFlagTokenFromCsrf "1234"

    get $ FlagMentorR flaggedId Flag token
    statusIs 200
```

where I have `getFlagTokenFromCsrf :: Text -> Handler Text`

The error I get when I try to `stack test` is:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Yesod.Core.Types.HandlerT App IO Text’
               with ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                       (YesodExampleData App) IO Text’
Expected type: Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                 (YesodExampleData App) IO Text
  Actual type: Handler Text
```

(Here's the [full example](https://github.com/Gizra/yesoders/blob/8fbf786bb33f046c4f1ee668c57e67a2f434e984/test/Handler/FlagMentorSpec.hs#L26-L36))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Yesod expert but what you are trying to do probably does not make sense: `getFlagTokenFromCsrf` is a server-side function that extracts some information from the request, hence it lives in `Handler a` monad because this is the monad for server-side code.

By contrast, Yesod tests are meant to be integration tests, asserting behaviour from the client-side against your `Application` (see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-test-1.5.3/docs/Yesod-Test.html). The functions there live in a different monad, namely `YesodExample site a` which manages requests on your behalf. This monad allows you to reuse part of your server code (routes, data types) and manage state of your DB but is otherwise totally uncorrelated with server-side operations.

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if you need some information generated on the server-side, you have to find another way to make it available on the client side.

Comment: I understand. I thought it would be possible to have unit-tests as-well.

Comment: Yes. Having unit tests in this particular case would make a lot of sense I think. Or finding a way to inject a known token on the client-side so that you can check from server's response if it actually checked token

Answer (score 3):

It seems I am trying to do something rather similar. That is: Try to run arbitrary `Handler a` functions in unit tests.

Some approaches I've tried and thought about:

1. The closest I've gotten that actually worked for me:

   ```
   import Application (handler)

   spec = withApp $ do
     it "" $ do
       liftIO $ handler $ someHandler
   ```

   Although [it seems this calls `makeFoundation` under the hood](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/f185eb8ad/Application.hs#L178), and I'd prefer if my handler would run in the context of the main webapp and not a separate instance.
2. To execute a handler in the main app's context, I've also tried to:

   ```
   import Foundation (unsafeHandler)
   import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State as ST

   spec = withApp $ do
       it "" $ do
         (YesodExampleData app _ _ _) <- ST.get
         liftIO $ unsafeHandler app $ someHandler
   ```

   Which has gotten me a type error like this:

   ```
   [34 of 35] Compiling Handler.FooSpec ( /path/to/test/Handler/FooSpec.hs, /path/to/.stack-work/odir/Handler/FooSpec.o )

   /path/to/test/Handler/FooSpec.hs:42:31:
       Couldn't match type ‘Network.Wai.Internal.Request
                            -> (Network.Wai.Internal.Response
                                -> IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived)
                            -> IO Network.Wai.Internal.ResponseReceived’
                      with ‘App’
       Expected type: App
         Actual type: Network.Wai.Application
       Probable cause: ‘app’ is applied to too few arguments
       In the first argument of ‘unsafeHandler’, namely ‘app’
       In the expression: unsafeHandler app
   Failed, modules loaded: Import, Utils, Foundation, [...]
   ```

   I'm not entirely clear on what might be the difference between `Network.Wai.Application` and `App`, but that might be the key to making this work.
3. I've also considered to specify a route to the handler, and then it would be accessible via `get SomeRouteR`. Although I'd rather not have to do this if I can help it.
4. I'm also considering refactoring some of my `Handler a` functions to `IO a`, and then I can use `liftIO` to execute them in not just handlers but tests as well.

That's as far as I've gotten. If I figure something more out I intend to update this answer. I've also starred this question so I get notified if someone else figures out something more or better.

Edit: [I've also asked this question on GitHub](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1301).

Edit:

I've found something rather promissing while trying to dig further in the direction of option #2:

```
import Foundation (unsafeHandler)

runHandler :: Handler a -> ST.StateT (YesodExampleData App) IO a
runHandler handler = do
  foundation <- getTestYesod
  liftIO $ unsafeHandler foundation handler
```

On which I was able to run test like so:

```
it "runHandler" $ do
  let
    testHandler :: Handler Int
    testHandler = do
      return 2
  runHandler testHandler >>= (==? 2)

  let
    testHandler2 :: Handler String
    testHandler2 = do
      fmap show $ (Import.runDB) $ insert (def :: User)
  runHandler testHandler2 >>= (==? ("UserKey {unUserKey = SqlBackendKey {unSqlBackendKey = 1}}"))
```